# Static resource cache issue - Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, caching

I have a spring MVC based application, where I have used spring MVC caching for static resource.

```
<mvc:resources location="/, classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/" mapping="/resources/**"
cache-period="${RESOURCE_CACHE_PERIOD}"/>
```

The **RESOURCE_CACHE_PERIOD** is property in a properties file with value as **2** (for development purpose).

The static resources such as .js files remain in cache after even change and I have to publish my application again to see the changes.

What might be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are changing the resources in your local code but not within the web container that is running your app.

Can you try altering the js from within the webapp that is actually running?

Comment: I am changing my .js file and the changes does not get reflected. However changes to my jsp are getting reflected. I am updating local file in both the cases.

Comment: You are running your code via an IDE and most likely you have setup the webcontainer via the IDE so it is doing the autodeployment of jsp for you (Eclipse?). Again: Can you try altering the js from within the webapp that is actually running?

Comment: I have deployment my maven project in my weblogic application server inside my eclipse IDE. Where do i find my webapp to alter the js file?

Comment: If you've installed via Eclipse without downloading WebLogic it might be running as an Eclipse plugin in which case you ll have to locate it manually under the Eclipse plugins section. But this is the content of a different question :)